# Change zeep binding

Tags: soap, binding, zeep

I'm trying to connect to a soap endpoint which defines 2 service location one is invalid. How can I change the binding to use the other service.
I'm new to SOAP and zeep the doc [says](https://python-zeep.readthedocs.io/en/master/client.html#using-non-default-bindings):

```
from zeep import Client
from zeep import xsd

client = Client('http://my-endpoint.com/production.svc?wsdl')

service2 = client.bind('SecondService', 'Port12')
service2.someOperation(myArg=1)
```

But it doesn't mention what are the argument.

My services are defined as:

```
<wsdl:service name="PackageInq">
<wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_IPackageInq" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_IPackageInq">
<soap:address location="http://invalid.local:8989/TopUp/PackageInq.svc"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="BasicHttpsBinding_IPackageInq" binding="tns:BasicHttpsBinding_IPackageInq">
<soap:address location="https://valid.com/TopUp/PackageInq.svc"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

I have tried things alike  `client.bind('BasicHttpsBinding_IPackageInq')` and getting:

```
ValueError: Service not found
```

Also if you know any good document that I can read, I would be glad if you recommend it.

**Update**
I found the correct syntax

```
client.bind('PackageInq', 'BasicHttpsBinding_IPackageInq')
```

but still when using

```
client.service.Method()
```

hits the invalid endpoint again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well after reading the doc more carefully 
`client.bind` returns a `service` and you are supposed to use that and not the client.

so it would be [like](https://python-zeep.readthedocs.io/en/master/client.html#using-non-default-bindings)

```
from zeep import Client
from zeep import xsd

client = Client('http://my-endpoint.com/production.svc?wsdl')

service2 = client.bind('SecondService', 'Port12')
service2.someOperation(myArg=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

zeep version 4.0.0.

```
         <wsdl:service name="RiskAnalysis">
            <wsp:PolicyReference xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" URI="#BasicPolicy"/>
            <wsdl:port name="RiskAnalysisHttpsSoap11Endpoint" binding="tns:RiskAnalysisSoap11Binding">
                <soap:address location="https://addreshere/"/>
            </wsdl:port>
            <wsdl:port name="RiskAnalysisHttpsSoap12Endpoint" binding="tns:RiskAnalysisSoap12Binding">
                <soap12:address location="https://addreshere/"/>
            </wsdl:port>
        </wsdl:service>


     from zeep import Client
        
     requestPayload = {'Attachment': inputQuery.encode() } 

     soapClient = Client('http://my-endpoint.com/production?wsdl', service_name=RiskAnalysis, port_name=RiskAnalysisHttpsSoap12Endpoint )
     soapClient.client.service.OPERATIONS(**requestPayload)
```